# How to make prompt current directory name in bold using powerlevel10k?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, zsh, prompt

I'm using `oh-my-zsh`, `powerlevel10k`, `colorls` and `fig` to customize my mac terminal. Now i have just one issue that i want the `current directory` name in **bold.**
[see pics to better understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5UPF.jpg)

Initially by default for full prompt directory length, the last directory was in bold but after i change to shorten directory the last dir name or current folder name went **regular** font. **I want it in bold**. How to fix it ?

And one more problem that **i want to change the color** of  which is placed at the starting of the each prompt. How to achieve it ?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what all you have changed, you may need to run `p10k configure` and generate a fresh `~/.p10k.zsh` file.

In that file, the setting you want to change is `POWERLEVEL9K_DIR_MAX_LENGTH=0`:

```
# Shorten directory if it's longer than this even if there is space for it. The value can
# be either absolute (e.g., '80') or a percentage of terminal width (e.g, '50%'). If empty,
# directory will be shortened only when prompt doesn't fit or when other parameters demand it
# (see POWERLEVEL9K_DIR_MIN_COMMAND_COLUMNS and POWERLEVEL9K_DIR_MIN_COMMAND_COLUMNS_PCT below).
# If set to `0`, directory will always be shortened to its minimum length.
typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_DIR_MAX_LENGTH=0
```

It may be tempting to change `POWERLEVEL9K_SHORTEN_STRATEGY` from `truncate_to_unique` to `truncate_from_right`, but `truncate_from_right` will instantly remove all your highlighted directories.

If you wind up with a path that has multiple expanded words such as `~/.c/z/zsh_custom/p/python`, you will want to look at the `local anchor_files=(...)` list and comment out anything that's causing a directory to be treated like an anchor if you don't want only the final directory expanded.

As for the color of , I'm not sure what that is from your question, but you might have better luck asking the developer on his [GitHub Issues project page](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/issues) rather than on StackOverflow.

Comment: ok...it's really helped me. Thank you very much.